# Trying to read a binary file and find a string which is entered by the user

Tags: c

Hi I am trying to create a function which will take input from the user in the form of a string search a binary file which contains football results e.g (Chelsea,liverpool,1,2) and print each time the string appears for example if the user enters liverpool then all of liverpool's results will be printed to the screen.The code I have does not print anything. What am I doing wrong? Here is what I have.

```
struct matches 
{
    //structure members
    char teamA [100]; 
    char teamB [100];
    int goalsA;
    int goalsB;
};    
void displayMatches()
    {   
        struct matches match; //declare variable of type struct

        char input[20]; //variable to take input from user 

        FILE * file1; //pointer to a file

        file1 = fopen("matches.bin","rb");//open binary file in read mode 

        if(file1==NULL) //error check for file
        {
            printf("open file error.\n");
            exit(6);
        }

        printf("Enter the team\'s results you want to view\n");
        scanf("%s",input);

        /*loop to read binary file check if input team 
         is in file if yes print the results for that team */
        while(fread(&match,sizeof(match),1,file1)) 
        {



            if(strstr(match.teamA,input))
            {

                printf(" %s %s %i %i ",match.teamA,match.teamB,match.goalsA,match.goalsB);

            } 
            else if(strstr(match.teamB,input))
            {

                printf(" %s %s %i %i ",match.teamA,match.teamB,match.goalsA,match.goalsB);

            }

        }

        fclose(file1);
    }
```

Comment: How does `matches.bin` look like?

Comment: shouldn’t be there `if(strstr(match.teamA,input) != NULL)`

Comment: Hi the format of matches.bin is teamA,teamB,goalsA,goalsB there is no newline after the team name

Comment: I suspect `matches.bin` that's probably a text file. Did you create a file by `fwrite`?

Comment: [void addResult()](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23446534/971127) is wrong.